# Debugging Flex 3 on 64bit Windows 7

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Does anyone know if any Flash 9 Debugger works on 64bit Windows 7?  The archive I found for the Version 9 Flash debugger doesn't mention 64bit.  I'm updating a project I created years ago.

I tried installing the most recent debugger for Flash 11, and weird things are happening.  String variables that I clearly initialize and assign are not showing up in the Watcher saying "errors during evaluation" and I'm not even sure whether the code is currently executing correctly in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know if any Flash 9 Debugger works on 64bit Windows 7

There is not a 64 bit version of the Flash Debugger, though, so you'll have to the 32-bit debugger.  But, yes the 32-bit Flash Debugger should work fine on 64 bit Windows 7.

I think I currently have the 11.2 debugger installed on 64Bit Win7 with no issues.

I do occasionally see situations where the Flash Builder Watch list acts wonky and shows errors like the one you describe.  But it is rare and usually fixed by launching a new/clean debug session.  I've never tried to replicate that error, though.

I suggest deleting all watch variables, cleaning the project, and trying again.  Add the things you want to watch back in slowly to see if the error reoccurs.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I'm nevertheless going to just see whether I get the same problems by working on my old computer.  Thanks for the info.